# Improving visualizer look

Tags: javascript, audio, canvas, fft

I am not happy with how this code draws this music visualizer using canvas and `getByteFrequencyData`. https://share.getcloudapp.com/Kou7AJb1

It seems the bars are too large and I think its because the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) array contains a wide spectrum of data but in my code I am generating n amount of bars based on the width of the canvas.

Then after having n bars I am mapping the FFT to the same index of the bar leaving out lots of useful information.

```
function convertRange(value: any, r1: any, r2: any) {
  return ((value - r1[0]) * (r2[1] - r2[0])) / (r1[1] - r1[0]) + r2[0];
}

// line up and down
const drawVisualizer2 = ({ canvas, frameData, background }: any) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // TODO: Improve?
  const bars = Math.round(canvas.width) / 15 - 1;
  const max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, frameData.fft);

  for (let i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
    const height = convertRange(frameData.fft[i], [0, max_of_array], [0, canvas.height / 2 - 20]);
    const centerY = canvas.height / 2;

    // draw the bar
    ctx.strokeStyle = background ? background.colors[0] : "#ffffff";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY + height);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY);
    ctx.lineTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY - height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

export default drawVisualizer2;
```

What I think needs to be done is average out the FFT based on the amount of bars in the loop. If that makes sense what is a practical approach code wise to achieve that?

I hope this makes sense, happy to clarify if needed.

Comment: Maybe you can add a sketch of how the bars look and how the bars should look like to better illustrate your issue.

Comment: Fair enough, the cloud app video contains how they currently look, these templates look better https://elements.envato.com/podcast-audio-visualization-pack-ETCVTNT is this enough to illustrate or do I need more details? Cheers :)

Comment: We're getting closer Michael ;) - I'm just unsure what you mean by 'the bars are too large'. Is an individual bar's stroke too thick? Or is the overall height of the bars too tall?

Comment: I think because the FFT array could contain lets say 500+ items and the loop is fixed at lets say 100 bars, the problem is it only reads the first 100 items of data in the FFT array. My assumption is it would look more natural if it was distributed more evenly. Does that make sense?

Comment: So I think the question is how do you take an array of i.e 100 items and proportionally spread it relative to a larger array i.e 500+ so it's balanced? Inside the loop instead of `frameData.fft[i]` there needs to be a pattern to find the correct index proportional to the current index which is relative to the total inside the fft array

Comment: Remember the rolling average from one of your previous questions? you can use that same strategy ... you need to simplify your problem, get canvas out and think about this just from a pure mathematical perspective

Comment: Yeah I need to revisit that one, I felt like there was something useful there. I also need to improve my math skills.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `frameData.fft` is the Uint8Array containing the actual frequency data returned by the `AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData()` method.

Your assumption is right - the number of bars of course doesn't match the number of items stored in array and with a loop like

```
for (let i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
...
frameData.fft[i]
...
}
```

you're just using the first few values from zero up to the number of bars and ultimately skipping the entire rest of the array.

The fix is quite simple though:

Instead of grabbing values from the array in intervals of 1, the interval must be the number of elements in the array divided by the number of bars. This number is then multiplied by the variable `i` inside the for-loop and rounded as the division might result in a decimal number and the array's elements are at integer positions.

Here's an example:

```js
let frameData = {
  fft: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
};
let bars = 5;
let steps = frameData.fft.length / bars;
for (let i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
  console.log(frameData.fft[Math.round(i * steps)]);
}
```

Comment: you still leaving out lots of useful information ... before it was skipping the end of the array, now is all over ... the proper output should be averaging the gaps